# Spring Integration - XML processing

Tags: spring-integration

I'm building an apllication that need to read and parse an XML file to start some jobs (each one based on the XML tag - below i show you an example of my XML, omitting the namespace).

Looking on SI project i've found this [example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples) that explain how to process XML file.

Before looking this i was trying to use a simple Unmarshalling process that create POJOS classes, this is good to parse it but many nested POJO will make my work very hard because for example some tags can be omitted (all are optional) and my program looks like an "infinite" `if-else`.

What i need to do is:

- Parse the file and for each tag start a JOB that make some operations

Right now i dont want to think about the job (even using Spring i've seen Spring Batch and in the future i would like to integrate it with SI, but right now i just only need to parse the XML)

In the example i've seen that is used `si-xml:xpath-splitter`, so looking my XML file i will need to create many splitter for each tag and then redirect to an appropriate channel ? For example `process` tag will be redirected to appropriate `service-activator`, `activity` tag to another `service-activator` and so on ?

The example (the link i've show above) is a nice good start, but on the net i havent found other examples where i can "understand" other aspect of SI-XML, for this i've asked here for a little help on how to get started.

Another little problem is all attriutes that i have in the tags, with Unmarshalling i can create an interface and then i know that all classes must implement it (and use it to run the job), but here (SI + XML) i dont know how to create something similar...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <activity attr="1" />
    <activity attr="2" />
</root>
```

**UPDATE**
Right now i've write this applicationContext in order to split each tag and redirect to appropiate channel but i'm having the error "**Cannot convert #STRING in NodeList**"

```
<si:channel id="rootChannel" />
    <si:channel id="activityChannel" />
    <!-- Here i split each tag of type activity -->
    <si-xml:xpath-splitter id="activitySplitter" input-channel="rootChannel" output-channel="router">
        <si-xml:xpath-expression expression="//process|//activity" />
    </si-xml:xpath-splitter>

     <!-- Here i want route the messages to appropiate channel each tag must be processed separately because will need to create a thread for each one-->
    <si-xml:xpath-router input-channel="router">
        <si-xml:xpath-expression expression="concat(name(./node()), 'Channel')" />
    </si-xml:xpath-router>

    <si:outbound-channel-adapter channel="activityChannel" method="dispatch">
        <bean class="it.example.Activity" />
    </si:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

This is the main class:

```
public class Probe {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        AbstractApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/META-INF/spring/probeProcessing.xml", Probe.class);

        MessageChannel messageChannel = (MessageChannel) context.getBean("rootChannel");
        GenericMessage<Document> probeMessage = createXmlMessageFromResource("/META-INF/spring/probe.xml");
        messageChannel.send(probeMessage);

        context.close();
    }

    private static GenericMessage<Document> createXmlMessageFromResource(String path) throws Exception {
        Resource probeRes = new ClassPathResource(path);

        DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        builderFactory.setNamespaceAware(false);
        DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document probeDoc = builder.parse(probeRes.getInputStream());
        return new GenericMessage<Document>(probeDoc);
    }
}
```

This is a part of the stack:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.integration.config.RouterFactoryBean#0]; nested exception is org.springframework.xml.xpath.XPathException: Could not evaluate XPath expression:com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.XPathException: Impossibile convertire #STRING in NodeList.; nested exception is javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException: com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.XPathException: Impossibile convertire #STRING in NodeList.
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:139)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:147)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:120)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:442)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:392)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:231)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:154)
    at org.springframework.integration.splitter.AbstractMessageSplitter.produceOutput(AbstractMessageSplitter.java:156)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:102)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:147)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:120)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:442)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:392)
    at it.dirimo.Probe.main(Probe.java:20)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what is the problem you see with the Spring Integration XML support when there is no any surprise unless standard XML processing: XPath, Marhsalling, XSLT etc.

The Spring Integration just provides EIP abstraction over there and allow you to make the messaging process for the XML documents as `payload`.

I think you go right way with the `<int-xml:xpath-splitter>`. For example using `//process|//activity` as a XPath expression.

After the `xpath-spliter` you can use `<int-xml:xpath-router>` to check the root element for the splitter document and route it to the appropriate channel.

**UPDATE**

> , how i can do to redirect to a channel simply from the tag? For exmample process redirect to processChannel and activity redirect to activityChannel... ?

Something like this:

```
<int-xml:xpath-router>
    <int-xml:xpath-expression expression="concat(name(./node()), 'Channel')"/>
</int-xml:xpath-router>
```

**UPDATE 2**

Well, I've found how it will work for your case. That `concat()` xPath works somehow only for documents. So you should add `create-documents="true"` to the `xpath-spliter`. And another `concat()` concern that we expect a `String` anyway. But `xpath-router` evaluates to the `NODELIST` by default. So you should add `evaluate-as-string="true"` to `xpath-router` configuration.

Tested locally - works well.

Comment: Thanks this could be a start. looking the example int-xml:xpath-router have an xpath-expression and serveral mapping, how i can do to redirect to a channel simply from the tag? For exmample process redirect to processChannel and activity redirect to activityChannel... ?

Comment: See an update in my answer. Looks like you should study XPath more! :-)

Comment: Mhhh... i need to study XPath without "more" :D Now i will study your expresson to understand it well and see if i will just able to make some system.output from different channels :)

Comment: Sorry but i'm having little difficult how to setup SI with splitter/router. I've updated my question with the applicationContext.xml that i've write. The error message i'm having is "Cannot convert #STRING into NodeList"

Comment: That error doesn't say so much. Would be better to see more stack trace .

Comment: i've updated the question with the main class and a part of the stack trace, the part where the exception is raised

Comment: So in my little (and confused :D) experience i was near the solution... during my billions of test i've used create-document and evaluate-as-string but never both togheter -.-'  Now i've created some other classes/tag and updating si-xml:xpath-expression with this new tag they will be redirected correctly!